# Profiler doesn't show my code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, profiler

I'm using profiler in Visual Studio 2012 to find bottlenecks in my code, but I found that after moving project to another computer, profiler doesn't show my code at all, but only modules names:

[image]

There is TrineaClient which is my project's module, but it doesn't show its functions as profiler wouldn't have knowledge about them. But so far I didn't have problems with this.

I understand it may not find symbols for some system modules or libraries that I'm using, but so far it always handled my own code.

What may be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you using? There is a difference in what is supported in for example the Professional and Premium/Ultimate editions (Professional has limited profiling specs). There is a [comparison chart](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs) but it is not extremely detailed. I was a bit disappointed with my Professional license since it no longer includes the developer edition of SQL server which used to include the SQL profiler (Express does not have the profiler). 3rd party tools could be a better choice than upgrading though.

Comment: @LouisSomers I'm using Professional edition, but I'm sure I previously used the same one and then I had access to this information. That's strange.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2011/05/13/vs2010-just-my-code.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I had "Just my code" option enabled.

Comment: So problem solved and should be posted as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(updated based on the fact that you're using Windows 8.1)*

Windows 8.1 came with some changes to the underlying system that the VS profiler uses when collecting information. If you update to Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (or newer) and profile again, symbols should be resolved correctly.

Generally, in the VS Profiler, when you see module names in square brackets where you would expect function names, it means that symbols for that module could not be resolved.

Comment: Yes, I have symbols for my code on new machine and the path is set correctly. Still it doesn't show it. +1 for answer which may work in some cases, but doesn't solve my problem, so I can't accept it.

Comment: What do you see in the output window when the report is opening? Does it say "Failed to load symbols for..."? Also, do you have any of the VS2012 updates installed? Are you on Windows 8.1 by any chance?

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1, yes. Previously I was developing under Windows 7 and Windows 8.0. Could it be the reason? I'll let you know about the output window in a few days as I don't have access to my project right now.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. Windows 8.1 came with some changes to the underlying system that the VS profiler uses when collecting information. If you update to Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (or newer), symbols should be resolved correctly.

Comment: Good to know that! Shame I didn't gave you this information at the beginning. Please, edit your answer so that I can accept it.